# Intensity deconvolution

Tags: distributions, descriptive-statistics, noise, nonparametric-density

We have a set of intensities (measured)

$I_{j} = \cos(\theta_{j}) + N_j$

where $\theta_{j}$ is distributed according to some distribution between 0 and 180 degrees (well, in reality between 0 and 360 but because of cos() we can't tell them apart) and $N_j$ is some noise (possibly weakly dependent on $\theta_{j}$).

From the cos() term we know that $I_j$ should be bound in [-1,1] but because there is an additive noise term some intensities are above 1 and some are below -1. We have hundreds of thousands of measurements so we have smooth looking histograms of intensities and it looks like the standard deviation of $N_j$ is ~1 although it is asymmetric and with very large tails (so not even close to Gaussian). The angle distribution is bimodal (peaks around 0 and 180).

Is it possible to/What would be the best way to

1) Find the underlying distribution of $\theta_{j}$

2) Estimate $\theta_{j}$ for each j.

Thank you in advance,

Ilya

Comment: This is called 'denoising' in signal processing. I can't help beyond that but it gives you somewhere to start :)

Comment: Thanks, yes, I've been looking into this/talked to some math phd friends but this is starting to look somewhat hopeless :/ This is a surprisingly very difficult problem, esp since I am not an expert in this type of signal processing.